# problem with dual amd graphics card amd radeon r5 A8 and radeon r7 m260

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, radeon, fglrx

Good day I have problem with dual AMD graphics card AMD Radeon R5 A8 and Radeon R7 M260. Hope, you can help me, I try to install drivers at additional driver in Ubuntu, try download and install from official website and I can't switch on Radeon R7 M260 on laptop.

I have only on amdcccle and no result.

---

Ok, I have laptop, I have dual graphics cards

1. AMD A8 radeon R5 Graphics (DDC Display AMD Radeon (TM) R5 Graphics)
2. AMD Radeon r7 m260 (Unknown display)

How can I install driver and switch GPU on radeon r7 m260?

---

```
sudo aticonfig --list-adapters
* 0. 00:01.0 AMD Radeon(TM) R5 Graphics        
  1. 01:00.0 AMD Radeon R7 M260
```

How to switch adapter?

---

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon APU A4-6000 with R2 Graphics] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2269
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
--
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2269
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

Comment: Install the driver by `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates`.

Comment: I try, but ubuntu see only amd a8 with r5 graphics, and can't see radeon r7 m260 :(

Comment: in AMD Catalyst 
DDC Display AMD Radeon (TM) R5 Graphics
AMD Radeon r7 m260 unknown display
Whats wrong?

Comment: Please who can help, install amd radeon r7 m260 in ubuntu. It's really?

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version and the fglrx version?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch them this way:

```
sudo aticonfig --px-igpu
```

to the integrated adapter.

```
sudo aticonfig --px-dgpu
```

to the descrete adapter.

Log off and log on after that.

You can see the status by

```
aticonfig --pxl
```

You can also switch the adapters using Catalyst Control Center  GUI utility.

**Note:** This should work on a supported Ubuntu version (14.04 or 15.10) and with the latest `fglrx` that can be installed by:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

Comment: It does not work can not see the graphics card only sees the integrated

Comment: Almost all have tried, well, there must be a solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

I has similar problem... try this

```
aticonfig --adapter=all --initial
```

after that, reboot and fglrx should now recognize both gpu's, then Piloto6's answer should work