# Intel / AMD hybrid card drivers on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I have a Dell notebook with two graphics cards: Intel HD Graphics 5500 / AMD Radeon M260

I had problems with other distros to install the drivers for the two cards. I researched and found information saying that the AMD card works with the native drivers of the Ubuntu installation. So, I'm now having a clean installation of Ubuntu GNOME 17.10 (I do not want to change it anymore). How can I know if the two card drivers are installed correctly? How can I test the AMD card?

Comment: Do you know which card are you using? This can be checked for example by `glxheads` command, that (apart from test graphics) displays name of the rendering device and driver

Comment: @Picek, the `glxheads` command returned:

`Name:: 0
   Display: 0x55f5fe130670
   Window: 0x3200002
   Context: 0x55f5fe172fa0
   GL_VERSION: 3.0 Table 17.2.2
   GL_VENDOR: Intel Open Source Technology Center
   GL_RENDERER: DRI Desktop Intel (R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)`

Comment: it seems that your system is using integrated card right now. I haven't faced this kind of problems since 14.04 where I used dual Radeon/Intel configuration. But there fluent switching between cards was only possible with Radeon's proprietary driver. It may have changed until then I can check more on that when I'm back to the old computer.
Edit: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/730110/problem-with-dual-amd-graphics-card-amd-radeon-r5-a8-and-radeon-r7-m260?rq=1] this seems to deal with a similar problem if I understood  properly

Comment: I have not found proprietary drivers for Ubuntu version 17.10. Do I need to make a manual switch to use the radeon card?